# Delivery Status Notification (Failure) - 553 Exception

Tags: email

Little help here. This was a message people were getting when trying to email me, but it was being not delivering.

553 Exception during HTTP GET to '/v4/domains/DOMAIN.com/internal'

- 'tuple' object has no attribute 'status_code''

I omitted my domain for this question and just put DOMAIN.com where it shows my domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Need context. Are you talking about your personal email account? Are you talking about functionality you programmed into a web server?

Comment: I have my work email (mynam@domain.com) ported to go to gmail, and it's worked fine for years. 

This is a message the sender received and I asked them to show me.

Comment: This is not the right site to ask that question